# Ereg on OOP select option

Tags: php, oop, select, ereg

I'm trying to create an ereg on a select option in object orientated programming for validation. 
Though it is always returning true even though the selected option isn't part of the ereg!

In my class I have the following:

```
function makeSelect($category, $fieldName){
    $a = '<div>'."\n";
    $a .= "<select name='$fieldName'>"."\n";
    $a .= "<option value='' selected='true' disabled='disabled'>Pick Category</option>\n";
    foreach ($category as $value){
        $a .= "<option value='$value'>$value</option>"."\n";
        }
    $a .= "</select>"."\n";
    $a .= "</div>"."\n";
    return $a;
}

function checkSelect($selectName){
    if(ereg('^[Pick]', $selectName)){
        $this->messageArray[$selectName] = "<span class='fail'>Please select field</span>";
        $this->testArray[$selectName] = false;
    }
    else {
        $this->messageArray[$selectName] = "<span class='ok'>Sweet</span>";
        $this->testArray[$selectName] = true;
    }
}
```

In my main file I'm setting the array as

```
$category = array(
    1=>'First Category',
    2=>'Second Category',
    3=>'Third Category',
    4=>'Fourth Category'
    );
```

And calling the checkSelect function as

```
$oForm->checkSelect('category');
```

Comment: **Warning:

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.**

Answer (score 0):

With calling `$oForm->checkSelect('category');` your expression would looks like `ereg('^[Pick]', 'category')` hence it would be always "true".

I think that you need to pass value from a form but not a name of element. For example.

```
$oForm->checkSelect($_POST['category']);
```

P.S. you could rewrite it to non deprecated code easily

```
preg_match('/^[Pick]/', $selectName)
```

P.P.S. it's better to rename `$selectName` to `$selectedValue`. You trying to check value, but a name.

P.P.P.S. also, your pattern would not match your values.